# Bootstrap 3 Column Site {height: 100%;} not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, height

I know this is a common problem and I feel really stupid for not being able to figure it out, but I have a 3 column layout in HTML, and I seriously cannot figure this out for the life of me.

Here is the basic layout of my site:

fixed header,
1 sidebar on each side,
middle area with content.

Here is a mockup of the site that I'm speaking about: http://eitanrosenberg.com/tests/pop/bootstrap/

It looks ok at first, but when the browser is resized, the sidebars get really small and there is a ton of white space. Why is this? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: do you mean when you scroll down? you see white under the side columns?

Comment: Yep! Exactly. I feel really dumb for not being able to figure this out, and it's been racking my brain all day.

Comment: I want it to span the entire height of the page... not just the browser space, but the entire document. and I've seen a lot of people answer in other questions that they would use position:absolute, but I  would really rather not do that. Floating everything left seems better for this project, especially since eventually I'm going to make it "responsive".

Comment: It's because your layout is relative to the window, not the content. So regardless of how much content you have, the sidebars will only be the height of the window. Ergo, you scroll down to see the rest of the content, and the sidebars cut off. What you need to do is find a way to make the layout relative to the content. Maybe make a wrapper that is relative to content with a min-width of 100%, then have your sidebars nested inside of that wrapper.

Comment: hmm. well I already have a wrapping div around both sidebars and the middle area. I assume you mean give the wrapping div a height: auto and width: 100% that changes with the content? I think I see what you're getting at but would like a little more clarification please

Comment: Also, it's not just the sidebars that are cutting off. For some reason the height: 100% of the HTML/body/wrapping div is cutting off/making it very short.

Comment: Any more advice or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Look at it this way.

The height:100% of the container div (and the column divs) gets their height from the body-element (100% of that), and the height of the body element is calculated as 100% of the height of the html element

The height of the html element is then (in practice) calculated from the current height of the browser window (100% of that).

So the height of your boxes will all be set to match the heigth of the browser window...

and this is exactly what you see when you shrink the browser window heigth!

Because:

Once your content no longer fits within the height of its container (ie. when you shrink the browser window you also shrink the calculated heights of all your containers and eventually the headroom will be too small) - overflow happens. The content of the "highest" box will then be the first to overflow, and parts of its content will then spill out of it to be visible below the boxes (since you don't use overflow: hidden).

The browser will then allow you to scroll past the bottom of the boxes (so to speak) in order for you to be able to see the content that "overflows the box", but it doesn't adjust the height of container - the boxes will still keep the same height as the browser window while you scroll...

So the background patterns will always be the height of 100% of the browser window in this example (an not match the height of the highest content when the height shrinks below that)...

One way to remedy this - is to adjust the height of the boxes with Javascript (calculate the height of the highest column and set that as an absolute value for height on the container and the boxes - every time the page resizes)

... or you could use "display: table" and "display: table-cell" on the container and the columns respectively as a workaround (overriding the Bootstrap grid CSS) for this particular layout width/media queries...

Hope this helps!
Good luck!

Comment: Somehow that did it! Thanks! Such a simple fix. I don't know why I didn't think to do this...

Comment: Ok, after thinking it worked for a while, I was able to finally view it on another computer and it doesn't work in webkit browsers (Safari/Chrome). I was thinking about just using jQuery, but there has to be a good way to do this in CSS!

Comment: Hmm - strange, it usually does ;)  - Could you link to your updated code? Perhaps we could help identifying what causes your troubles (if there's a devil in your details so to speak) if we could take a look at it in it's entirety?

Comment: Oh - and one more thing. I wasn't very clear about it (sorry 'bout that) - but I assume you noticed that you need to reorder your columns in the source code (to left - content - right) in order to make the "display: table" based solution work properly?