# 2 columns with 100% width bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an existing project which I need to migrate to the bootstrap 3 framework.
The existing one is written purely by me, and uses a two column layout.

Trying to get the same result in bootstrap gets me nowhere, those stupid gutters 
are using padding which adds the background-color in between the two boxes (columns).

Here is a screenshot:

[image: example]

If you look closely you can see the background color exceeds the border (A result of the freaking gutters)

Bottom line the design I'm aiming for is this:

http://i41.tinypic.com/2hz4avc.png

Is it possible to do so without modifying the gutters / removing them.

Comment: Please Check this link on before on stackoverflow [link][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14656097/bootstrap-3-column-site-height-100-not-working

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Comment: Without seeing your code there isn't much anyone can troubleshoot. Could be as simple as adding a class to your `.row` to remove the padding in any child columns. In BS4 there is a baked-in class for that but in BS3 you have to insert your own.

Answer (score 0):

I think, without seeing any code, that it could be a problem with the padding not being taken into account when the width is calculated.

This is an issue with box sizing: http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/boxsizing.html

try:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```